# what happend to my Iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, iterator

Hi in my problem exist a object `classA` like below
    typedef map myMap ;

```
static string keys[3] = { "11" , "22" , "33" };

class classA {
   myMap::const_iterator m_iterators[3];
  int classA::SetIterators(const myMap &AllData)
}

int classA::SetIterators(const myMap &AllData)
{
    m_iterators[0]=AllData.find(keys[0]);
    ....
    return VALID;
}
```

in `SetIterators` function I want to ensure if some key exist in the map and set `iterators` to them
when I am exist inside of `SetIterators` the iterators are set properly.
but after return they miss their value and set to Bad Ptr.

I call to `SetIterators` like below.

```
 int classA::BuildView(const myMap &AllData)
 {
      if(SetIterators(AllData)== VALID) 
 }
```

How does that happen? How can I prevent this?
Thanks herzl.

Comment: Can you show the code that calls `SetIterators`?

Comment: Since the problem, according to your description, is with the caller, why don't you show how you use the class?

Comment: Knowing the exact type of `AllData` would help. Also, are you absolutely sure that the iterators become invalid because the function returns? In other words, does another part of your program access `AllData` in the meantime? If yes, what kind of access?

Comment: other thread that build this Data and here I get this data by refrens but I don't thinks this is the prolblem.

Comment: My guess is that you pass in a temporary copy of `AllData` somewhere higher in the call tree.

Comment: @aaz: That sounds like a very plausible reason. You should submit it as an answer.

Comment: @aaZ: You right. it is answer. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Iterators will be invalidated when new values are added or removed from the map.

Comment: This it not true when he is really using a map.
Map iterators are still valid after insert and erase operations.

Comment: yes but this happend all time exactly after return this can't be other thread that change it each time in same step.